# iPad inbox out of date

Tags: iphone, ipad, mail.app, email, exchange-activesync

I have a work email account that uses Zimbra as the backend server. For my iDevices, I set up this account as an exchange account and everything usually works fine. On my laptop, it's set up as IMAP (for some reason I can't set it up as exchange there).

My problem is that when I read mail on my MacBook and move it to another mailbox, it doesn't always update the inbox of the iPad. My iPhone seems to be fine though. I'm seeing old mail still in the inbox even after I slide down the message list to "refresh". Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know if the Zimbra server you have is the open source edition or the network edition?

Comment: I have no idea since it's managed by my employer. The about page says it's version 7.2.4_GA_2900 if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I went through the settings to see what might have been different. The only thing I noticed was that I was syncing "unlimited" emails on my iPad but only a month on my phone. I changed the setting on my iPad and the inbox seems to have cleaned itself up. We'll see if it sticks. I'll mark this as answered tomorrow if it does.